# Apache HTTP error 500 on file upload

Tags: php, apache

Whenever I try to upload files to my website I get 500 error and notification that server couldn't handle request. I tried to configure `upload_max_filesize` in both, `php.ini` and `.htaccess`, but nothing works. I also tried to set value of `MaxRequestLen` in `apache2.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
  MaxRequestLen 20000000
</IfModule>
```

EDIT: I can't post whole code because it contains sensitive data, here are parts of it:

```
$files = $_FILES["images"]["name"];
$tmpNames = $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"];
$archiveName = time();
$folder = "./uploads/";
$price = 0;

foreach ($imagesFormats as &$imageFormat) {
    if (!file_exists($folder.$archiveName."/".$imageFormat)) {
        if (!mkdir($folder.$archiveName."/".$imageFormat, 0777, true)) {
            addError("Error while trying to create directory.");
        }
    }
}

foreach ($_FILES["images"]["error"] as $key => $err) {
    if ($err == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = basename($_FILES["images"]["name"][$key]);
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $folder.$archiveName."/".$imagesFormats[$key]."/".$name);
    }
}

if (Zip($folder.$archiveName."/", $folder.$archiveName.".zip")) {
    rrmdir($folder.$archiveName."/");
} else {
    addError("Error on archiving.");
}
```

Comment: Did you check your log files ? 
should be there /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: where's the php for this and the codes used to upload with? You're not going to get any magic answers with what you posted and didn't post.

Comment: Voted to close as unclear since there is no supported code in regards to the answer posted, the php tag and the question itself. This will serve no one in its present state.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I posted one part of code, but it's totally irrelevant to the question. It may serve someone who doesn't know that mb_strlen() is not available on default.

Comment: @Nikola Thank you Nikola; now the question will help others now, *cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved - I didn't knew that [`mb_strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) function is not available by default in PHP but should be installed.

Comment: you never posted that code or any php

Comment: @Fred-ii- Code is very broad, if I posted it I would have to post it completely but there is lot of sensitive data in it. I posted one part of it.